# Trouble in installing arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ at Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arm

I finished an RPi3-based project under Ubuntu cross-environment one year ago. Now, the environment was crashed for some other reason. I would like to rebuild my environment. The Makefile is correct for it's approved that time.

When I tried to make it, I got "make: arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: Command not found".

Then I tried to install it by command: "sudo apt-get install arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++" but got
E: Unable to locate package arm-linux-gnueabihf-g+
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-g+'

Then I tried to install it by command: "sudo apt-get install arm-linux-gnueabihf-g+" but got
E: Unable to locate package arm-linux-gnueabihf-g

Then I tried to install it by command: "sudo apt-get install arm-linux-gnueabihf-g" but got
E: Unable to locate package arm-linux-gnueabihf-g
How come? How can I setup my cross-environment for RPi3 under Ubuntu?

Comment: The package name I find is `g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf`. Have you tried using that instead?

Comment: It works. BTW, could you tell me how you find the package name?

Comment: I googled the name you were trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael said, the package name is g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf. So, I used "apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf" and it worked.